# Unable to see Data in Kafka Topic

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I have a json file in S3 bucket and I am pushing that file into kafka topic, Can some one guide me why I am not able to see this data in Kafka topic. My Program has no errors and running correctly.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
import time
import boto3


def json_serializer(data):
    return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers= ['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=json_serializer)
def read_s3():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('s3sparkbucket')
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        return body
if __name__ == "__main__":
          body=read_s3()
          producer.send("Uber_Eats",body)
          print("Done")
```

Comment: What is you consumer command line?

Comment: You need to flush the producer and try running your consumer before the producer. By the way, your object loop returns on the very first object

Answer (score 0):

KafkaProducer must need 3 params:

```
bootstrap.servers  key.serializer and value.serializer
```

May be caused by that

Comment: Serializers are optional